# Errores Android Studio al programar Java

Tags: java, android

Soy nuevo en programación, me estoy especializando en Java para desarrollo de aplicaciones Android, de momento he estado aprendiendo en Eclipse pero, ahora con la nueva herramienta Android Studio, tengo problemas, al programar en el archivo .Java me da errores en ciertas instrucciones. Voy a dejar algunas fotos y agradecer que alguien me aclare estas dudas.

[image: Errores de Android]

Comment: Por favor comparte los errores, la imagen no nos dice nada

Comment: El c'odigo pertenece a un proyecto creado con swing no tiene nada que ver con Android, te sugiero iniciar con lo b'asico, como crear una aplicaci'on android.

Comment: @Jhon Además, cuando compartas código, por favor incluilo como texto, no como imagen. Es más claro (la imagen puede no verse bien en algunos celulares) y permite copiarlo para evaluarlo o responderte.

Answer (score 1):

Las clases que muestras en tu codigo para construir la UI de tu aplicacion como son JFrame, JPanel no son propias del Android SDK.

Tienes que instalar [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419)

y te recomiendo iniciar desde lo basico con estos tutoriales:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuqoGJ4Y5NM

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su pronta respuesta. Me pondré entonces a ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me pondré entonces a ello.

Answer (score 0):

Para programar aplicaciones Android tienes que usar su framework no puedes usar jswing

Comment: Vale, me pondre a buscar el APi de Android entonces.

Comment: Mejor busca un tutorial sobre como hacer  tu primera app Android yo es que te recomendaría la web de desarrolladores de Android pero esta en inglés.